# Register ASP.NET Core ILogger<> from built-in logging mechanism to Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, autofac

I have a ASP.NET Core app using Autofac as DI container. I'm also using built-in logging mechanism that provides ILogger<> dependency. Now I'd like to register it in Autofac. How?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special for this to work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As already stated, when you use the official [autofac-integration for asp.net-core](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-with-configurecontainer) you don't need to do anything. If you still want to do it manually, which is legit, you could do the following in the `ConfigureContainer` method.

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
   // ... more registrations
   builder.RegisterInstance(new LoggerFactory())
                .As<ILoggerFactory>();

   builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>))
          .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
          .SingleInstance();
}
```

Keep in mind that their is no specific logging-provider added.

Comment: It's the answer

Comment: I'd love to use the `don't need to do anything` option mentioned, but it isn't working, so perhaps a better explanation could help?

Comment: I had some trouble with `ILogger<>` vs just `ILogger`. Perhaps I can post a better code example.

Comment: You cannot just use ILogger without type definition. That would need special container configuration and is therefor not possible with the default setup of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: So, I was using just `ILogger` not sure how, and maybe it didn't work, it was just there. So I changed them all to `ILogger<>` and I think it is fine now, just had to refactor some things. I used this answer to register in the Autofac container. Thanks!

Comment: also, I didn't register the factory, so maybe that will cause me issues, but I'm still confused about mixing the built-in container with Autofac, in order to NOT have to register the Logger stuff, but it works now, will have to research later to understand better how the built-in container works with Autofac.

Answer (score 0):

You can register merge services registered in `IServiceCollection` with Autofac. To do that add the following to `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // register classes in IServiceCollection
    ...

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // register services in Autofac
    ...

    builder.Populate(services);

    var container = builder.Build();
    return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

Comment: This should return Autofac service provider rather than manually resolving IServiceProvider, which rather seems like an anti pattern. https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html